# With an mRNA-vaccine, would it hypothetically be possible to get that sequence transcribed into their genome for people who suffer from a retrovirus?

Tags: virology, rna, coronavirus, vaccination, retrovirus

I recently read a bit about the mRNA-vaccines for COVID-2019. I fully understand that mRNA cannot enter the genome of a healthy person as they lack the required reverse transcriptase to transcribe RNA back into DNA. This made one question pop up in my head, though:

What about the people who **do have** reverse transcriptase in their body? As far as I understand it, a retrovirus like HIV does express the required proteins to form reverse transcriptase as it's part of the virus strategy to integrate itself into the human genome.

Wouldn't that mean that an HIV-positive person, upon being vaccinated using an mRNA-vaccine, could theoretically end up having the RNA-Sequence of the vaccine transcribed into their genome if reverse transcriptase is present in their cells at the right moment? Or am I missing something? Would that mean that the COVID-vaccine could essentially become the artificial equivalent of an endogenous retrovirus, even possibly immunizing future generations?

Comment: It’s relevant to note that all humans have reverse transcriptase from retrotransposons and mRNA can be reverse transcribed and integrated into the genome (this the mechanism by which processed pseudogenes arise).

Comment: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/25392/why-is-the-new-mrna-vaccine-unable-to-modify-human-dna

Comment: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/53027/155

Comment: "if reverse transcriptase is present" - Case is use of rev. transcr. from HIV virus by CoV. There lies some analogy in  the fact that LINE1  which is a retrotransposon mentioned by canadianer above is being used by ALU elements to have themselves integrated.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, there's recent news [we may all have some reverse transcriptase activity and in some people it leads to serious disease](https://medicalxpress.com/news/2021-02-common-hiv-drugs-vision-loss.html).  The specificity of that reverse transcription is not yet known, but HIV reverse transcriptase is going to require a [primer binding site](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3475395/) - basically some lysine tRNA sequence - to get started.  Of course, with low odds, there may be some conceivable way to get around that by mutation, template switching, etc., but I don't know of evidence it happens.

Reverse transcription of random RNA transcripts (including the genomes of mRNA viruses that infect us) is surely a theoretical possibility, but we should bear in mind how rarely this must occur (otherwise, our genome would be even more overflowing with spam than it is).

Comment: The scientific PNAS article underlying the reverse transcriptase press release is [available here.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gerald-G-Schumann/publication/348971198_Cytoplasmic_synthesis_of_endogenous_Alu_complementary_DNA_via_reverse_transcription_and_implications_in_age-related_macular_degeneration/links/60228d0fa6fdcc37a8142985/Cytoplasmic-synthesis-of-endogenous-Alu-complementary-DNA-via-reverse-transcription-and-implications-in-age-related-macular-degeneration.pdf)

Comment: Reverse transcriptase is not the whole story as I learnt. There must be "integrase" or the like to put it in (so to say). What is known about "free floating" DNA - retrotranscribed or not - "going into" host cells DNA strains? Any idea? Maybe that is rather unknown, do you know? I refer to the mechanism of integration in a narrow sense; how is viral DNA being put into (so to say) host DNA, if there is no integrase?

Comment: @Peter Bernhard - getting the DNA into the cell is "transient transfection", while integrating it is "stable transfection".  See https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8067914/ .  I don't deny that, in the absence of a viral vector or some other trick, stable transfection of random DNA in any given cell is *very rare*.

Comment: "...how rarely this must occur..." If there were a working principle that integration kills the infected cells (e.g. not by apoptosis, not like cytotoxic t cells) integration might be more common, and the less searched for (as that would be a way to get back up again).

Comment: @Mike Serfas Thank you for providing the link. You name it:  "The specificity of that reverse transcription". I think it would be interesting to read more on that issue in your answer. Provided link refers to my comment above which refers to Canadianer's. That link refers to ALU as one, special specifity of LINE1, I think. Are there any others or pertaining sources you know of?

Comment: "Even in non-retroviruses that lack integrase, such as the adenoviruses, integrase may be expressed through genetic engineering technique", this struck me first in the link you, Mike, provided above. What is the natural mechanism for integration of DNA, that comes in as such, not as RNA? Counterintuitively, integration of DNA suddenly seems more intricate than "integration of m-RNA" (because the enzymes are combined or not?). From your paper: DNA viruses, how do they integrate, in case they do?

Comment: From first link in your answer: "The buildup of a certain type of DNA in the cytoplasm, Alu, contributes to macular degeneration, the researchers found. This buildup appears to kill off an important layer of cells that nourishes the retina's visual cells." - This seems higly relevant in the context of the question, but not only, as it leads to some hypothesis that "integration kills" infected cells: no need to inherit embedded vaccine... Again: if integration kills, that's good if it's infection?

Comment: The first link you give is good. You point at some issue you should elaborate on, as it's about "specifity" you speak of: They say, "Different retroviruses use different host tRNAs as primers. HIV-1 uses Lys3." How can specificity lie in such thing as  tRNA. t for trivial? Sure there is some basic knowledge underlying. - If possible, more on "promoting" integration specifically, but, even more so, more on unspecific integration and if it exists. Thank you.

Comment: Is, in your opinion, specificity of insertion, of integration in a narrow sense, no issue? The question refers to transcription "into" the genome. So even if by unspecific HIV-retro-transkriptase were produced CoV-DNA that couldn't be inserted because of lack of integrase? ("transient DNA") 
The paper linked in your answer surprisingly does not tell how insertion by HIV is produced. There is no integrase. Thus, HIV looks like illustrating some paradigm unknown: specific DNA may integrate into host DNA because it's specific, No enzyme needed. That cannot possibly be? Some other answer on that?

Comment: I think your answer is way not explicit enough about the rather exciting "result" the study linked to in you first sentence offers. All this may go unnoticed to people like me who think they knew already. Please be more elaborate about the HIV enzyme being blocked, thus having blocked not insertion of HIV RNA/DNA, but of ALU RNA/DNA. Again, retro-transcriptase of HIV was found to work on something totally different? Thus, "...to get around that by mutation, template switching, etc.," seems obsolete, not necessary.